# How to insert a row when cell value changes in a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, insert

How to insert a row with value equal value of first row when cell value is different above cell in column `H:H`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to insert a new row and put the header row to the inserted row using Google Apps Script.
- In your question, you want to insert the new row when the value of column "F" is changed. But when I saw your sample image, the column is "H" instead of "F".

  - Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your actual goal. So in this answer, I would like to propose 2 patterns.
- From [your following replying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66608750/how-to-insert-a-row-when-cell-value-is-different-in-column-ff-google-sheet/66609216?noredirect=1#comment117750552_66609216),

  > The script is perfect. Can you modify the Text Color is RED and Fill Color is Yellow like a sample.

  - You want to put the values with the red font color and the yellow background color.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please set the sheet name. And, in this sample script, the values of column "F" are checked. When you want to check the values of column "H", please modify `"F2:F"` to `"H2:H"`.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheetname.
  
  // 1. Retrieve values from the column "F".
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  let [temp, ...values] = sheet.getRange("F2:F" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  
  // 2. Create an array including the row numbers for inserting new rows.
  const insertRows = values.reduce((ar, [v], i) => {
    if (v != temp) {
      ar.push(i + 3);
      temp = v;
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // 3. Retrieve header row.
  const header = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  // 4. Insert new rows and put the header row to the inserted row.
  insertRows.reverse().forEach(i => {
    sheet.insertRows(i);
    sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, header[0].length).setValues(header).setBackground("yellow").setFontColor("red"); // Modified
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- This sample script is used for your question and the sample image. So when you changed the structure of your Spreadsheet, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [insertRows(rowIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsrowindex)

Comment: The script is perfect. Can you modify the Text Color is RED and Fill Color is Yellow like a sample.

Comment: @tt3 Thank you for replying. About your additional request of your replying, I modified the sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike: The script is perfect and thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @tt3 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. By the way, how about [your latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66610813/7108653)? I'm worry whether I could correctly understand about your goal.