# Copy and Paste to the next Column + Last Row (GOOGLE SCRIPT)

Tags: google-apps-script, copy-paste

I would like to copy and paste to the next column + last row.
I try below but doesn't work and please see sample picture

```
function CopyPasteFrTo() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shfr=ss.getSheetByName('From');
  var shto=ss.getSheetByName('To');
  shfr.getRange('A1:N').copyTo(shto.getRange("A1"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  shfr.getRange('A2:F').copyTo(shto.getRange(shto.getLastRow()+1,1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  shfr.getRange('K2:N').copyTo(shto.getRange(shfr.getLastColumn()+1,7), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  shfr.getRange('G2:J').copyTo(shto.getRange(shfr.getLastColumn()+1,11), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

[see sample here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c431.jpg)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue and your goal from your sample image. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And when I saw your sample image, it seems that you want to copy the values in the same sheet. But when I saw your script, you want to copy the values from "From" to "To" sheet. By this, I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for this.

Comment: By supposing your goal, I proposes a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When I saw your sample image, it seems that you want to copy the values in the same sheet. But when I saw your script, you want to copy the values from "From" to "To" sheet. From this situation, I would like to believe your goal as your sample image.
- In your sample image, for the same sheet,

  - You want to copy the cells "A2:F" (last row of the data range.) to the column "A" of the next row of the last row.
  - You want to copy the cells "K2:N" (last row of the data range.) to the column "G" of the next row of the last row.
  - You want to copy the cells "G2:J" (last row of the data range.) to the column "K" of the next row of the last row.
  - Your sample image is as follows (This is from your question.).

    [image]

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheetname.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange("A2:F" + lastRow).copyTo(sheet.getRange("A" + (lastRow + 1)));
  sheet.getRange("K2:N" + lastRow).copyTo(sheet.getRange("G" + (lastRow + 1)));
  sheet.getRange("G2:J" + lastRow).copyTo(sheet.getRange("K" + (lastRow + 1)));
}
```

#### Reference:

- [copyTo(destination) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)