# How to Query a column where numbers are mixed with text (GOOGLE SHEET)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using a query to pull data from a multi-sheets in Google Spreadsheet that is populated by a Google Form. If the form has only numbers, there is no problem. However, if there's a mixed of text and number then it did not work.

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A:S;Sheet2!A:S},"SELECT* WHERE Col4<>''",0)
```

EDIT: Added the second one here:

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!A:S,"SELECT A,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,R WHERE G IS NOT NULL ORDER BY G LABEL R 'FRUIT'",TRUE)
```

Regards,

Comment: @Tanaike: would you please help on the second one.

Comment: In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. By the way, how will you do this your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66610813

Comment: @Tanaike: Accepted & Upvoted. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is how QUERY works. It only pulls the most frequent data type per column. To pull mixed data types, you can use `FILTER`:

`=FILTER({Sheet1!A:S;Sheet2!A:S},{Sheet1!D:D;Sheet2!D:D}<>"")`

Comment: That worked but how about this  ''=QUERY(Sheet2!A:S,"SELECT A,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,R WHERE G IS NOT NULL ORDER BY G LABEL R 'FRUIT'",TRUE)''

Comment: There are too many unknowns without being able to see your data and types. However, keep in mind that Stack and other forums are designed to share knowledge ("how to") in small units with a lot of people. Forums are not places where people can get free coding or formula-writing services. I encourage you to learn how FILTER works and how virtual arrays work. Beyond that, your best bet for receiving help will be to share a link to your sheet so others can see your data; then you may receive more replies.

Comment: Sorry about that. I got only the number in second Query in column H but there's mixed of text and number. Let me try it. Thank for your help